# Spring data mongodb query for subdocument field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

I'm using Spring Data's CrudRepository with mongodb and i have some issue to write a query which will select a document with specific subdocument value. Here's an example:

```
{
"_id" :,
"_class" :,
"matchHeader" : {
    "suspend" : {},
    "active" : true,
    "booked" : true,
    "eventId" : NumberLong(1009314492),
    "status" : ""
},
"matchInfo" : {

    }
}
```

}

i need to select the document with specific **eventId** field in **matchHeader** subdocument. i tried to write a function like this ***findByMatchHeaderEventId(id)*** but it doesn't helped at all.how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Property traversal for nested properties is explained in The [Spring Data MongoDB Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

You need to properly define your domain object class (constructor/getters/setters omitted):

```
public class MyDocument {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private MatchHeader matchHeader;
  private MatchInfo matchInfo;
  ...
}

public class MatchHeader {
  private Map<,> suspend;
  private boolean active;
  private boolean booked;
  private Long eventId;
  private String status;
}
```

and your repository class

```
public interface MyDocumentController extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {
  public List<MyDocument> findByMatchHeaderEventId(Long id);
}
```

Otherwise you can try the *findByMatchHeader_EventId* suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try

> findByMatchHeader_EventId

instead of

> findByMatchHeaderEventId

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query for preparing a custom query for fetching documents with specific subdocument Key value.

In your case, you can code like:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("matchHeader.eventId").is(id));
```

Note: But for Query you will be required to use MongoTemplate.