# Nested query in mongodb using spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to use nested `Mongodb` query but it does not work.
It is similar to [Spring data mongodb query for subdocument field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887505/spring-data-mongodb-query-for-subdocument-field)

But suggestions mentioned there does not work.

Please find my documents below.

```
@Document
public class Ticket {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @DBRef
  @CascadeSave
  private Customer customer;

  // getters and setters   
}

@Document
public class Customer {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String firstName;

  // getters and setters
}

public interface TicketRepository extends MongoRepository<Ticket, String> {

  public List<Ticket> findByCustomerFirstName(String firstName);

  }
```

I tried both `findByCustomerFirstName` and `findByCustomer_FirstName` but it does not work. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

These suggestions are right it should work...

Official docs explains it as you did it:http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

> Property expressions can refer only to a direct property of the
>   managed entity, as shown in the preceding example. At query creation
>   time you already make sure that the parsed property is a property of
>   the managed domain class. However, you can also define constraints by
>   traversing nested properties. Assume a Person has an Address with a
>   ZipCode. In that case a method name of
>
> `List<Person> findByAddressZipCode(ZipCode zipCode);`
>
> creates the
>   property traversal `x.address.zipCode`

Just one thing, remove `@Document` from `Customer` and try it, `Mongodb` didn't support join queries (I'm not sure if now it does)... so you're document should be `Ticket` and it must have a `embbebed document` `Customer` as a inner object and not in a different document.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I forgot to mention @DBRef annotation i used for customer. Reason is because i would like to access customer independent of ticket as well. Could u please suggest any alternative approach

Comment: Yes it works with inner documents :) but am looking for a way with linked documents –